# LVIT: w/ coil "spoiler": how much impact on inductance and Q

Tags: coil

I've been reading about a linear displacement sensor known as a [Linear Variable Inductance Transducer (LVIT)](https://www.hgsind.com/blog/lvit-technology-what-it-and-where-does-it-fit-sensor-world).   This uses a movable conductive shield over a coil to modify the inductance.   The shield is referred to as a "spoiler".

Note the spoiler is nonferrous, eddy currents are created in the spoiler, which I assume decreases the inductance compared to a free standing coil.

*My question is how much does moving the spoiler onto the coil change the effective inductance?*  Is it likely to be approximately linear to the position?

Online coil calculator like [Coil32](https://coil32.net/online-calculators/one-layer-coil-calculator.html) allow me to model a single-layer coil, but do not assume any sort of spoiler is present.

Comment: Model it as a transformer, with the secondary shorted, and fairly poor mutual coupling. Moving more of the spoiler over the coil increases the coupling.

Comment: OK, seems like I need to model the self-inductance of the spoiler, but it's not round wire.   Let's say the spoiler is an aluminum tube 100 mm long, 10 mm outside diameter, inside diameter 8mm.